Database Re-platform to GCVE
We have to re-platform a on-premise database of 1 TB from on-premise Oracle to Oracle on GCVE.  On-Prem is connected to GCP using dedicated interconnect.
What will be fastest way to transfer this database so it can be restored on GCVE ?

@ zen2012  I have edited my answer based on ur comment. let me know  how can  I help u further?
